# Is there a way I can find out if my data string is being passed on to my php function

Tags: php, forms, jquery

I am calling a ajax form submit script as given below :

```
$(function() {
  $('.simple-success').hide();
  $("#submit_button").click(function() {


        var firstname=$("input#Firstname").val();
        var lastname=$("input#Lastname").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var title = $("input#title").val();
        var organization = $("input#organization").val();




var dataString = 'firstname='+ firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&title=' + title + '&organization=' + organization;  


            $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "optIn.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
          $('.emailform').fadeOut(100).hide();
        $('.simple-success').fadeIn(100).show();
         alert('sucess')

      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

The script is pulling in the data from the form as I am able to view the data in an alert of the datastring.However for some odd reason the data never gets sent on to the database even though the PHP script seems correct. The PHP script is given below

```
<?php


    $firstname = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));

    $lastname = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
    $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $title = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    $organization = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['organization']));


$pdbHost = "localhost";
$pdbUserName = "******";
$pdbPassword = "******";
$pdbName     = "db1080824_emails";



//  Connect to mySQL
$conlink = mysql_connect($pdbHost, $pdbUserName, $pdbPassword);
if(!$conlink) {die('Unable to connect to '.$pdbHost);}
if (!mysql_select_db($pdbName, $conlink)){die('Cannot find database '.$pdbName);}

//SQL query

    $SQL2="INSERT INTO  `db1080824_emails`.`emails` (`record_id` ,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`title`,`organization`)VALUES (NULL ,  '".$firstname."',  '".$lastname."',  '".$email."',  '".$title."',  '".$organization."')";

    mysql_query($SQL2);
//  Connect to Closing the connection
mysql_close($conlink);
?>
```

The mysql server is located on the server and the database with tables has been created,so I am not sure whats going wrong here

Any inputs would be great

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I am already doing validation within the form itself ,so thats been taken care of,this additional validation in the php file is not even needed

Comment: ouch.. anyone could hack your server easily with curl or the hackbar addon.  Client side validation is fun but not effective in any way.

Comment: @MFrank2012: Validation has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Comment: not neccesarily frank.  If your server side validation checks for '/^[A-Za-z0-9]/' then the validation guarantees no SQL injection would occur.  As a general rule, I do agree.

Comment: I guess I need to do some reading then,I am sorry,but can you please provide some inputs on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: MFrank2012 - very simply, the contents of `$_POST` could contain *anything at all*. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

You can echo everything you need in php and alert it like this:

```
success: function(html) {
      $('.emailform').fadeOut(100).hide();
    $('.simple-success').fadeIn(100).show();
     alert(html)

  }
```

It will also show errors occured in php file.

Comment: you can also check your sql errors like this: mysql_query($SQL2)or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

First option: Use xdebug. http://xdebug.org This is the best option, as it will give you full debugging support and can help you fix a variety of PHP/MySQL problems. However, it can be a pain to get set up right, and depending on your environment it may not be an option.

Second option: View the PHP error log. The location of this log depends on your server setup. If you're using a hosting service, this should be available through the host's control panel. If your server is Linux with Apache, the log will usually be either in your Apache log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log or similar) or a vhost log file (a logs folder in the same location as your document root). Many PHP errors can be quickly diagnosed and fixed by just checking the log.

Third option: Print an error string. Try this:

```
if( !mysql_query( $SQL2 ) ) {
    die( 'Error ' . mysql_errno( ) . ': ' . mysql_error( ) );
}
```

Then check the response in Firebug or a similar tool.

And whatever you do, make sure you sanitize those inputs. Never assume any data coming from a web client is safe, because it's trivial to POST arbitrary data to a form. Try this: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php