# What are the steps I should take to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection

In response to a [previous question I had posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552612/is-there-a-way-i-can-find-out-if-my-data-string-is-being-passed-on-to-my-php-fun/9553253#9553253),there was a response that I was opening up my database to SQL injection. The code is given below :

```
    <?php


        $firstname = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));

        $lastname = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
        $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $title = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
        $organization = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['organization']));


    $pdbHost = "localhost";
    $pdbUserName = "******";
    $pdbPassword = "******";
    $pdbName     = "db1080824_emails";



    //  Connect to mySQL
    $conlink = mysql_connect($pdbHost, $pdbUserName, $pdbPassword);
    if(!$conlink) {die('Unable to connect to '.$pdbHost);}
    if (!mysql_select_db($pdbName, $conlink)){die('Cannot find database '.$pdbName);}

    //SQL query

        $SQL2="INSERT INTO  `db1080824_emails`.`emails` (`record_id` ,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`title`,`organization`)VALUES (NULL ,  '".$firstname."',  '".$lastname."',  '".$email."',  '".$title."',  '".$organization."')";

        mysql_query($SQL2);
    //  Connect to Closing the connection
    mysql_close($conlink);
?>
```

A suggestion was that I can do server side validation checks for '/^[A-Za-z0-9]/' to ensure no sql injection might happen but is that sufficient or is there best practice I should follow to ensure data sanitization ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection - read more on how it's done and how to "undo"

Comment: Use only ever prepared statements. Period.

Comment: First step:  **stop using mysql_query** and use a modern API like PDO or mysqli.  Both support prepared statements -- which, when used properly, go a long way toward preventing SQL injection.

Comment: But how do I use prepared statements when the information is coming from a form ?

Comment: exactly the same way as before

Answer (score 3):

Use prepared statements. Seriously. An easy way to do this, is to use the database wrapper [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) of PHP.

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = …;
…

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO  `db1080824_emails`.`emails` (`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`title`,`organization`)
  VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :title, :organization)');
$stmt->execute(array(
  ':firstname' => $firstname,
  ':lastname' => $lastname,
  ':email' => $email,
  ':title' => $title,
  ':organization' => $organization));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) to prevent SQL injection. Only this function is enough.

And, what @knittl said, using prepared statements is also a very good method to prevent it. But the normal mysql_* libary doesn't support that. You need a libary as PDO or MySQLi for things like that. I suggest you to switch to PDO or MySQLi, because in higher PHP versions the mysql_* libary be would deprecated.

Some other tips to improve your code:

- don't use `die()`. If you make a mistake you won't die, so why a computer? It is better to handle errors nice and put them on place you want them.
- `mysql_close()` isn't needed. PHP close every connection at the end of the execution.
- use error handling on the query, if the query returns false there is a problem. Also check with [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql-affected-rows) or [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql-num-rows) if the query has done something.

---

I order to answer the comments on this answer. You should use mysql_real_escape_**string** only for strings. If you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` be sure you have put quotes (`'`) around the string in the query:

```
$query = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'";
```

If you use intergers or any other number you should use [typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) and not the escape function:

```
$query = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id = ".(int) $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: You can use mysql_real_escape_string, but only if you know what you're doing. i.e. only use it for values enclosed in quotes (but for _every_ such value), have the right encoding set on the client side (PHP) as well as on the server/connection side (mysql). There's just so much where you can miss a little thing and be screwed again.

Comment: this function is NOT to prevent any injections. Go figure

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've updated my answer with some information. @Col.Shrapnel why is this function not for preventing SQL injection? From php.net: `If this function is not used to escape data, the query is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks.`

Answer (score 0):

I've been using PDO, I believe that this protects from injections:

```
$db_user = "****";
$db_pass= "****";
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=yourdatabasename; host=localhost";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO
        emails(firstname, lastname, email, title, organization)
        VALUES(:firstname,:lastname,:email,:title,:organization)';
$data = array(':firstname'=>$firstname,
              ':lastname'=>$lastname,
              ':email'=>$email,
              ':title'=>$title,
              ':organization'=>$organization);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($data);
```